# Colorize output from remote less

Tags: bash, pty

I know this is kindof crazy. I like to get crazy.

I have a local log colorizing bash function that I wrote. I decided as an experiment that I want to try to use it to colorize the output when I ssh into a server and run `less` on one of the logs. I can do this successfully with `tail`, but not with `less`. Is there a way to use my bash function locally to colorize the less output being returned through ssh?  This is what I have tried:

```
function colorwrap {
   while read -r line; do
      echo "$line" | colorlog
      #printf "$line" | colorlog
   done < <("$@")
}
```

Invoking it like so:

```
colorwrap ssh -t servername -C less /logs/server.log
```

With `echo` it seems to work a little bit. I can scroll up and down with `j`, `k`, etc. but things like search and `:` don't show up on the screen. But I can quit via `:q` even if I can't see it. Also, the colorizing works. But the scrolling is choppy and it's hard to do searches. I'm not even sure it is doing the searches I try to do.

I don't really understand how the control commands work, but I'm guessing it has something to do with terminal allocation and/or echo not interpreting correctly control characters.

Any tips on how to make this work? Or alternative *nix tools that can be used locally to wrap an interactive program running remotely?

Comment: You're running a separate instance of `colorlog` for every line. That's... yeegh.

Comment: And running `$@` unquoted is **always** wrong. Without quotes it behaves identically to `$*`, meaning that all your arguments are glommed together into a string, and then that string is split on characters in IFS, and then the pieces are each expanded as globs.

Comment: Anyhow -- before being able to answer this, we'd need to see how you're actually trying to invoke this function. (And as an aside, it's better form to write `colorwrap() {` than `function colorwrap {`; the latter is a bashism, whereas the former -- with no `function` keyword -- is guaranteed to work on all POSIX-compliant shells).

Comment: oops, my bad. I must have deleted that part by mistake.

Comment: (`echo -e` is also inappropriate here -- it means that the remote stream can't contain the characters `\n` without them being replaced with a newline, for example. That said, `echo -e` is actually inappropriate pretty much everywhere -- it's actually illegal for `echo -e` not to print `-e` on output, and bash *can* be compiled to have a compliant `echo` that does so by default).

Comment: Yeah, i realized I meant to do capital `-E`. Just a second I will change all of the above. Is there a better way than running `colorlog` every line?

Comment: `printf '%b\n' "$line"` is the compliant equivalent -- you don't want to honor placeholders like `%s` in the data, after all.

Comment: And yes, the better approach is to pipe the whole stream into just one instance of `colorlog`.

Comment: `colorwrap() { "$@" | colorlog; }`. And you need to make sure that if that's piped into `less`, it gets the `-R` option so it passes color sequences through.

Comment: waaaaitaminute. You're trying to run `less` **remotely**?! Oh. Yeah, you can't reasonably expect that to work.

Comment: Yeah, that's the main thing I'm trying to figure out. Like I said, a little crazy.

Comment: Is there a reason you run `less` on the remote side rather than the local side?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152870/discussion-between-xdhmoore-and-charles-duffy).